# Use a gateway's ethernet switch with a different DHCP server

Tags: router, wireless-router, dhcp, switch

I have Comcast Business internet, but currently operate their gateway without its DHCP server or wifi adapter (I have my own connected via Ethernet). I would like to use the gateway's builtin ethernet switch, but retain my current DHCP server. Is there a way I configure it that way?

Comment: Since you have effectively isolated your network from the Comcast Modem (just using Comcast Internet), I suggest you add your own switch to your network.

Comment: What is stoppingg you from just plugging devices in each port and them just working? (I dont have Comcast, but if all the devices are in the same subnet it does not matter which device in the subnet does dhcp - as long as only one does)